# React Router - routes from separate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building small SPA web app with react, react router and semantic. Problem appeared when I decited to move my routes from main .jsx to separate file. I wanted to create something similar to [this](https://alligator.io/react/react-router-map-to-routes/) and theoretically everything works well but components in routes are 'undefined'.

My project structure looks like this:

```
root
 |_ src
     |_ config
     |   |_ routes.js
     |   | ...
     |_ app
         |_ index.jsx
         | ...
```

routes.js:

```
import { Main, Add } from 'views';

export const routes = [
  {
    component: Main,
    path: '/',
  }, {
    component: Add,
    path: '/add',
  },
];
```

Index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { routes } from 'config';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map(props => <Route {...props} />)}
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

When i put console.log(routes) into the render I got something like that:

```
[
  { component: undefined, path: "/" },
  { component: undefined, path: "/add" }
]
```

and I have no idea where the problem may be.

Comment: is 'views' inside another folder?

Answer (score 0):

You components being imported in the routes.js file need to have a be specified a path like `import { Main, Add } from '../views';`

```
import { Main, Add } from 'path/to/views';

export const routes = [
  {
    component: Main,
    path: '/',
  }, {
    component: Add,
    path: '/add',
  },
];
```

Comment: I have set path to Views in webpack so path does not cause a problem because I use this method in other places and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

> App.tsx

```
import routes from "./routes";
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            {routes.data.map((entry) => {return (<Route {...entry}/>)})}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

> router.ts

```
const routes = {data: [
        {
            key: "one",
            path: "/three"

        },
        {
            key: "two",
            path: "/two"
        }
    ]
}

export default routes;
```